# Under CC BY-SA 3.0, will SE give me the source code if I wanted to imitate the Code Review beta for in-house purposes?

Tags: discussion, licensing

I was wondering, since [the license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) aligns with being able to use the layout / design, ***as long as credit is given***, if I would be able to see the source code of how to program the question/coding format. (Can you already do that?)

I am not concerned with the "voting" aspect of the site, but rather how to create the question format and tags (code, bold, italic). I have practically 2-3 months experience with web-based applications and would not have any clue how to do this from scratch.

The reason behind my developing of something similar would be for a group of programmers to show our code (in house), without needing to go to Stack Exchange, and review it/make edits. It would also be a little bit more private.

The question / commenting format would be all I am really concerned with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're really interested only in the [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) to HTML conversion, then Stack Overflow seems to use [PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) on the client and [markdownsharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) on the server, both are open source.

Though what you're describing sounds like a job for a wiki, and [there is a huge number of those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software), I think some of them support Markdown too (most have their own formatting language, including the most well-known, MediaWiki).

Comment: Yep, this is more aimed at what I was asking. Mainly the formatting of code/comments/text which seems like that's what Markdown is. I looked at other 'clones' and they aren't really that appealing - so I think I will take a closer look at this. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

> I was wondering, since the license aligns with being able to use the layout / design...

The license footer states something different:

> site design / logo © 2014 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required

The design, site and all the code in it is under a "all rights reserved" license. The *content* (questions, answers, comments, tag wikis and similar) is under the CC-BY-SA.

Comment: Totally overlooked that semi-colon. Great catch - thanks for the comment, @Bobby.

Answer (score 6):

The software is [not open-source](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/852/3773).

It's [available but expensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16055/139866) (and I don't know whether it's available as source code).

There are [several clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/139866) if you'd like to look at those.

Comment: Thanks, ChrisW! I'll take a look at the links you provided.